# zsh tab completion not working specifically for running `zsh <SCRIPT>`

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

In general tab-completion is working fine with zsh, except when I try to execute a script as in:

```
zsh script.sh
```

In this case if I write `zsh sc[TAB]` I get nothing.  Are there known fixes, or possible explanations for what's causing this?

---

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

My existing settings from `zshrc`:

```
# share history across multiple zsh sessions
setopt SHARE_HISTORY
# append to history
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
# adds commands as they are typed, not at shell exit
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
# do not store duplications
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
# ignore duplicates when searching
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
# removes blank lines from history
setopt HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS

# setup autocompletion
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
# autocompletion using arrow keys (based on history)
bindkey '\e[A' history-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-search-forward

setopt prompt_subst
autoload -U colors && colors
local resetColor="%{$reset_color%}"
PS1=""
PS1="%F{cyan}"'($(basename "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV")) '"$resetColor"
PS1+='%n%{$reset_color%}@$(scutil --get ComputerName):'"$resetColor"
PS1+=$'\e[38;5;211m$(short_cwd) ';
PS1+=$'\e[38;5;48m[$(git_repo):$(git_branch)] ';
PS1+='$resetColor$ ';
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute a `script.sh` that is located in the current working directory, or one that is found via a loop-up it in components of `$PATH`? If the latter, note that `zsh` doesn't do that by default. Only in `sh` or `ksh` emulation.

Comment: You'll also likely want to use `%F{211}` instead of `$'\e[38;5;211m`, and see `%f` to restore the foreground colour to defaults. `%m` for the computer name.  See also `%~` for a short cwd. Or `%2~` for any even shorter ones and other builtin ways to truncate long strings in the prompt.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in the CWD

Comment: I can't reproduce with that `.zshrc` (that file put in an empty dir and zsh started as `ZDOTDIR=that-dir zsh`) and the same version of `zsh` though with that `.zshrc`, `zsh` is hardly usable, because of the missing `%{` around some of the escape sequences (which have no reason to be in the first place as per my comment above).